# Why does adding `& string` fix/improve the intellisense of `keyof`?

Tags: typescript, intellisense

If I use the straight `keyof` operator in TypeScript, the intellisense when I mouse over that type will be just `keyof TheType`. Whereas if I add `& string` it will give me the far more useful union list of strings.

```js
type Foo = {
    a: string; 
    b: number; 
    c: () => void; 
}; 


type A = "a" | "b" | "c"; 
//type A = "a" | "b" | "c"

type B = keyof Foo; 
//type B = keyof Foo

type C = keyof Foo & string; 
//type C = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Why is this?

Comment: My guess is [this change to TS4.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#smarter-type-alias-preservation) is responsible for the `keyof` being preserved and that intersecting with `string` is forcing evaluation

Answer (score 2):

A key can either be a string, a number, or a symbol.

```js
const sym1 = Symbol();

type Foo = {
    a: number,
    2: string,
    [sym1]: boolean,
}

type keys = keyof Foo;

type isString = keys extends string ? true : false;
//type isString = false

type isKey = keys extends string | number | symbol ? true : false;
//type isKey = true
```

When you do `keyof Foo & string`, you are basically only selecting string keys.

To get better intellisense, you can do this :

```js
type showKeys<T extends keyof any> = T extends any ? T : never;

type keys = showKeys<keyof Foo>;
//type keys  = "a" | 2 | typeof sym1
```

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the edits !